# What is this R.id.home?

Tags: android, back-button

Multiple parent Activities for one child activity toolbar Back Button

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I have to Override this function for the functionality of the back button, call back to the same parent activity from which the child is called but I don't understand this code of line:
 `id == android.R.id.home`
What is the `R.id.home`? `home` represent for? is I have to use the same `R.id.home` Everywhere, where ever I have to use this back button functionality in my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably used to using `R.id.whatever` to refer to the IDs you've given to the views in your app. Giving a `TextView` an ID of `label`, and then you can find it by looking for the view with `R.id.label` for its ID, that kind of thing.

That `R` file is generated for your app, based on the resources you've added or declared. But **`android.R.id.home`** is an ID in **Android's** `R` file - you can think of it like a separate set of system resources. It won't conflict with anything you've given a "home" ID to, because that would be `R.id.home` instead.

When you call `setHomeButtonEnabled` on your toolbar, Android adds its own icon, and it gives that an internal ID of `android.R.id.home`. That's always the identifier for that home button, and you can check if it's been pressed by checking for that ID when a menu item is selected.

Comment: detailed explanation! it's solved my confusion. thanks @cactustictacs

Answer (score 0):

`R` is the way to get things from the Android resources pack. `id` is telling it that you want an `id` from it (you can also ask it for other things, like `string`s).

`home` is the actual ID that you are asking it for. It is probably a button judging by your question. IDs are set in the view editor.

[image: Editor window]

If you have a search around your application, you will probably find a button with the ID `home`.

Answer (score 0):

A very short answer is: a way of **accessing resources**. 
Resources could be `TextView`, `Button` and also  some `Strings`, `Drawable` images as well.

`R.id.home` represents some particular resource which is `MentuItem`, so this way the code determines if the `MenuItem` is selected or not - there could be several `MenuItem` in the `Menu` so, the code finds out if the `MenuItem` with `id`=`home` selected or not.

You should have something like this in your `Menu` HTML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/home"        
    android:title="BlaBlaBla"
/>
...
```

*Important note: every resources must have different identifiers (**id**) to avoid ambiguous accessing.*

Here you can find detailed information about `R` with explained use cases. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources)